# JavaFX: bind disable property of a button to ObservableList size

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, observablelist

I have a `TableView` and I would like to bind the disable property of a `Button` with the size of the `ObservableList` model of the table. In particular, I would like to disable the button when the size of the `ObservableList` is grater than 2.

How can I achieve that?

To disable another button when no row is selected in table I used

```
editRoadButton.disableProperty().bind(roadsTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
```

Is there a similar way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are factory methods for useful bindings in the Bindings class. In your case f.i.:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.size(items).greaterThan(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that

```
ListProperty<String> list = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.<String>emptyObservableList());
Button foo = new Button();

foo.disableProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() {
    {
        bind(list);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        return list.size() > 2;
    }
});
```

Comment: What about memory leaks? I have to call unbind? Where?

Comment: Personnaly I do my bindings on a configure() method, and unbind everything on unconfigure() method. It's depend how your program is done but my unconfigure are called when I changed the view to another.
It's the same if you add listner, you have to remove them